# Need to block users from accessing the "MANAGE CONTACTS" option

Tags: contacts, settings

We want all contacts created by users on Android's phones to go to the O365 email account and therefore we need to block the ability to change the SYNC ACCOUNTS inside CONTACTS - MANAGE CONTACTS.

Different phones' brands and OS versions.

Any ideas will be appreciatted.